# How to tidy angular html?

Tags: angularjs, html, tidy, htmltidy

I'm using tidy-html5 from brew, and i can't tidy up my angular templates because they use custom elements like those :

```
<due-diligence-point index="1" title="Lead Screening">
```

This throws this error on tidy-html5 :

```
line 26 column 9 - Error: <due-diligence-point> is not recognized!
```

There is an option i'm skipping or this will just not work with tidy ?

The only option i have is to populate manually "new-empty-tags" ?

Comment: found any solutions ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've asked this before [prettier](https://prettier.io/) existed, which completelly solves this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party of one here but have you tried prefixing your element with the 'data-' tag? The following succeeds an HTML5 validator.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>asdf</title></head>
<data-custom-tag></data-custom-tag>
</html>
```

If you remove the data prefix however it will throw an error as an unrecognized element.

Comment: even if it would have worked that should not be the approach, idea is to make tidy work for angular not to change angular code altogether.